# javascript variable not changed

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a little program to reverse a string and I'm using this approch:

```
var reverse = (str) => {
    let returned = [...str];
    for(let i = 0; i < returned.length; i++)
    {
        let symetrical = returned.length - i - 1;
        let temp = returned[i];
        returned[i] = returned[symetrical];
        returned[symetrical] = temp;
    }
    
    return returned.join("");
}
```

but when i test the function like `reverse('123')` I got the same input as result?

why the `returned` variable didn't change?

Comment: Did you step through it in a debugger?

Comment: Tip: JavaScript swapping isn't this hard. `[ r[a], r[b] ] = [ r[b], r[a] ]`

Comment: There's also `str.split('').reverse().join('')`

Comment: The problem is that your loop is swapping each pair of elements twice. This is a common mistake in exercises like this. Change the loop to stop at the halfway point of the array.

Comment: @Barmar Yes That was the issue , thanks y'all

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the function by creating two arrays, the array of the letters of the param str, and the results array which takes the `length - 1 - i` algorithm you had:

```js
let reverse = (str) => {
    const arr1 = [...str];
    const arr2 = []
    for(let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
    {
        arr2[i] = arr1[arr1.length - 1 - i];
    }
    
    return arr2.join("");
}

console.log(reverse("abcde"));
```